# Meteor.js: Get anonymous visitors unique ID/ip/whatever?

Tags: meteor

Let's say I'm building an app using meteor.js where I just collect some simple form data from users. Maybe an answer to a simple question or something. They don't need to log in to submit data.

**How can I protect my app from someone creating a js-loop in their Chrome Console that just inserts crap into my DB?**

---

I can protect removal and updates by doing this:

```
Formanswers.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  update: function () {
    return false;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return false;
  },
});
```

And if the user was logged in (which as you remember is not the case in my app) I could timestamp each insert and check something like:

```
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
        if (userId && (Formanswers.findOnd({userid: userId, time: SOMETHING TIME SPECIFIC}).count() < 1)) return true;
  },
```

So my question is: is there any other way of getting a unique userId-thing or IP-address or something for an anonymous (not logged in) user so I can do the above check on him as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You can use a meteorite package.

accounts-anonymous

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous

So you use

```
Meteor.loginAnonymously();
```

if the user visits your page for the first time, and use .allow to check what you need

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need! I'll try it out.

Comment: I'm getting [this error](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous/issues/1) when I install accounts-anonymous :(

Comment: It's not maintained any longer, https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous/issues/1#issuecomment-13323466. But I guess it would be easy to create something similar.

Comment: Ok.. API has changed, so you need modify it like this on server.js

http://pastebin.com/5J3yaduw

Comment: This fork of accounts-anonymous seems to be up to date (as of April 4, 2013) github.com/pulsecat/meteor-accounts-anonymous

Answer (score 1):

To get the ip address, the observatory (https://github.com/jhoxray/observatory) project uses this:

in coffee:

```
Meteor.userIP = (uid)->
  ret = {}
  if uid?
    s = ss for k, ss of Meteor.default_server.sessions when ss.userId is uid
    if s
      ret.forwardedFor = s.socket?.headers?['x-forwarded-for']
      ret.remoteAddress = s.socket?.remoteAddress
  ret
```

Which returns an object like `{ forwardedFor: '192.168.5.4', remoteAddress: '192.168.5.4' }`

Comment: I'll test this. What would be REALLY great though is if they made a separate package with only the client-IP-check-thing, as that's all I want in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a session or localStorage key. When the visitor submits the form check if the key has been set, and if it has, reject the insert.

Comment: I didn't know you could set Sessions on the server? Can you? A localStorage key sounds hacky?

Comment: No - do all of what I'm saying on the client. You prevent the client from inserting into the client db, based on a key - set in session or localStorage. Of course this solution is not without vulnerability: the visitor would have to poke around in the browser console, notice what the key is doing, and write a script to clear it after each form submit. But we're talking about one very determined visitor.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Session.set('currentuser', 'something randomly generated by another function');
    }
}
```

and check if the 'currentuser' already has inserted in your database.

Comment: Yeah but couldn't someone just write a script which reloads the browser window (which sets a new currentuser-Session), runs an insert and then repeats? Or am I too paranoid?

Comment: Yes you are right... But there must be an possibility catching the same "user", because the Meteor users account system remembers your login in even after closing the browser. Or you allow an insert only every 5 minutes by setting an intervall. Simple but not very smart...

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to log the user in or even create a user, just keep a record of IF the current visitor has inserted something and then insert som kind of insert-limit for him.