# Meteorjs: getting visitor's ip address

Tags: meteor

I can't seem to find this anywhere in the docs and all info on google is one stackoverflow post which is rather incomplete. I have an application which does geoip and I need the visitor's ip address. Not logged in user, all visitors.

Any ideas how you do this with meteor?

UPDATE: After more searches I found this code which seems to work so far:

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');

__meteor_bootstrap__.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    Fiber(function() {
        console.info(req.connection.remoteAddress);
        console.log(req);
        next();
    }).run();
});
```

but there's a problem. I can't link the ip address with the visitor itself since I can't send cookies or set session data from the server to the client like I would normally do in PHP/Python/Ruby.

I got the full request with it's headers but no visitor session id or something to pick this user out from the crowd.

Think of an application where you need to send a chat invite to all users from UK for example. You first need to geoip him then send the invite if everything matches up. So I need this back and forth.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755563/meteor-js-get-anonymous-visitors-unique-id-ip-whatever

Comment: That doesnt work anymore. `console.log(Meteor.default_server.sessions);` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I did not say it works, just that it's kind of a duplicate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok so here's how I got it working. It's not pretty but it works. When a client opens your page you have to call a server method ASAP:

```
Meteor.call("get_visitor_ip");
```

Then on the server you have the method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    ...
    "get_visitor_ip": function() {
        this.setUserId(this.userId ? this.userId : new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str);
        var user_ip = get_visitor_ip(this.userId);
                    // Do whatever you need with it
    }
    ...
});

get_visitor_ip = function(uid) {
    var k, ret, s, ss, _ref, _ref1, _ref2, _ref3;
    ret = {};
    if (uid != null) {
        _ref = Meteor.default_server.sessions;
        for (k in _ref) {
            ss = _ref[k];
            if (ss.userId === uid) {
                s = ss;
            }
        }
        if (s) {
            ret.forwardedFor = ( _ref1 = s.socket) != null ? ( _ref2 = _ref1.headers) != null ? _ref2['x-forwarded-for'] :
            void 0 :
            void 0;
            ret.remoteAddress = ( _ref3 = s.socket) != null ? _ref3.remoteAddress :
            void 0;
        }
    }
    return ret.forwardedFor ? ret.forwardedFor : ret.remoteAddress;
};
```

Comment: I'm having trouble sifting through this code to find out what I need to JUST get the IP address when the user is anonymous.

Comment: This looks like compiled coffeescript, which is harder to read than just regular coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

The meteor [user-status](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) package keeps track of IP addresses of all connected users, and a bunch of other stuff.

See a demo at http://user-status.meteor.com/.

Note that with both this package and other methods you will have to specify the number of reverse proxies the server is running behind, as documented here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_onconnection

**Disclaimer**: I am the maintainer of this package.