# meteor app: how to get a unique session/client id without using accounts

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

In my meteor app, I need to be able to capture some form of unique element (session id/client id, etc...) to help keep track of the actions that user makes. At this point, I'm not using accounts package, so I'm just looking for a way to capture some sort of client-unique data element, which I could use in the data model to  track activities/steps of every unique user.
What application / browser / session element could I use in place of this unique id string?

Comment: You should take a look at answers from [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755563/meteor-js-get-anonymous-visitors-unique-id-ip-whatever)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](http://docs.meteor.com/#random) what you are looking for?

You can just use `Random.id()` to get a unique id string. I have used this a number of times to track temporary objects and it is super helpful. There are other `Random` methods too that may come in handy.

Comment: Would Random.secret() be a better choice than Random.id() for unique session id?

Comment: You definitely could use `secret()`, but ID's are not necessarily meant to be like passwords, they are more just meant to be unique, to limit conflicts. If you are creating passwords for people (like recommending one for them), then secret would be a good route. But I like the easier readability of `id()`, especially when I need to troubleshoot something :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can try to use is DDP connection's session ID `Meteor.connection._lastSessionId`. But be careful, because it is basically websocket session. So when the client open a new tab or refresh the page, this sessionId will be different .

If you want to keep the same session in the browser you can try to implement your own localStorage based session.

Answer (score -1):

Some thoughts: Instead of using Meteor's `Random.id()`, insert a new doc into a Mongo collection, this way you are guaranteed there will be no collisions. As there is always a tiny chance that `Random.id()` will return a duplicate. Is that a correct assumption?

Meteor docs say `likely to be unique`, i.e. Not guaranteed to be unique.
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random

Store the _id of the doc in a `Session.set()` call, to use as your anonymous userId, i.e. `Session.get("anonUserId")` When done you can delete it to keep the collection trim.

Comment: No-no-no. Don't do that. Believe me it will be unique in our life time. Seriously..